# Format datetime in pandas dataframe using strftime

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas data frame of the format

```
  0                             1    2    3
0 2010-02-12/08:14:24.280000 0.12 0.45  0.66
1 2010-02-12/08:15:24.333000 0.14 0.55  0.77
```

I want to create another column 4 having same data as column 0 and format the time data till seconds ("%H:%M:%S")

```
     0                          1     2    3       4
0 2010-02-12/08:14:24.280000   0.12 0.45  0.66  08:14:24
1 2010-02-12/08:15:25.333000   0.14 0.55  0.77  08:14:25

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/efw_20100213.csv', header=None)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
df[4] = df[0]
df[4].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

but the output is still showing in ns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) attribute after converting to timestamp series. The following command should do the trick:

```
In [26]: pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Out[26]:
0    08:14:24
1    08:15:24
Name: 0, dtype: object
```